# MySQL row_number in where cause not returning data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the second 10 records from a table with this query but I get no data returned.  Take out the where cause and I get data but I have to skip over the first 10 records to get what I am really interested in, trying to avoid that.

```
SET @row_number = 0; 

SELECT 
   `Ship Date`,`Order Number`,
  (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rowid
FROM input_data
WHERE (@row_number>10)  
order by @row_number  
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f5256/7 <-- i have created a sample query here, have renamed the the columns for ease...although i agree with @Bill Karwin, but my approach is just easier.

Comment: You can't use `@row_number` or (the alias) `rowid` in `where` of a same query and `order by @row_number` doesn't make sense. Why do you generate row number based on ordering from the `@row_number` variable itself? Imagine a 100m meter dash run, will the winner be the one who cross the finish line first or will the winner be the runner in lane "number 1"?

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause cannot reference variables set in the SELECT-list. Despite the order of clauses, the expressions in the SELECT-list have not yet been evaluated as the WHERE clause is filtering rows.

I think you want:

```
SELECT `Ship Date`, `Order Number` FROM input_data
ORDER BY ...something, I don't know what...
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Or if you use MySQL 8.0, and can use window functions:

```
SELECT `Ship Date`, `Order Number`
FROM (
  SELECT `Ship Date`, `Order Number`, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...something...) AS rownum
  FROM input_data) AS t
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, you need to wrap your query into an outer select so rowid is evaluated

```
SET @row_number = 0; 
select * from (
SELECT 
   `Ship Date`,`Order Number`,
  (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rowid
FROM input_date ) A
WHERE A.rowid>1  
order by rowid
LIMIT 10;
```